# Getting error while creating new angular4 App

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am getting the following error while creating the angular4 new App.

**Error:**

```
Error: Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.
Path "/app/app.module.ts" does not exist.
```

I have node version `9.4` and `angular-cli version 1.7.1` and when I type like below.

```
subrajyoti@subrajyoti-H81M-S:/var/www/html/angular4-learning$ ng new myapp
```

I have also the write permission o this folder but still getting the above error. Here I need to resolve this error so that I can create new App.

Comment: This is strange, or you on Linux or OS X?
Did you install the CLI globally or locally?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and cli installed globally.

Comment: Do you have execute permission for those files? if not try `chmod +x *` in the app's root folder

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error, First I thought the issue is in npm but when I ran "npm audit" it shown me 0 vulnerabilities. Then I came to know that issue might be in angluar cli.
So I have removed the angular cli, cleared the npm cache and install fresh angular cli.
It works!

**Steps that I followed:**

1. `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache`
3. `npm install -g @angular/cli`
4. `ng new NewProject`

Answer (score 0):

I just attempted to recreate this issue without any luck.
Steps:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new foo
This worked successfully for me.
```

macOs
node: 8.9.0
npm: 5.6.0
@angular/cli: 1.6.3

Comment: I can create it from other directory location but particular from some directory it could not create.